# Issue reading JSON file with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON file containing this:

```
{"users":["john","peter"]}
```

I tried to do a Ajax request, and it returns the two names in the users array, up until now everything is working fine, however, when i try to edit the JSON file, whether using PHP or manually, lets say i add two more names to the users array, like this:

```
{"users":["john","peter","George","Robert"]}
```

I save the JSON file, reload the page and I try to do a ajax request once again, but for some reason it returns the two names that I had prior to adding the two new ones. Instead of returning

```
["john","peter","George","Robert"] it does return ["john","peter"]
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

here is my Ajax request:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();                        
request.open("GET","../file/data.json",true); 
request.send(); 
request.onload = function(){ 
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText); 
    console.log(data); 
}
```

Comment: how you are reading `json` file? show your `ajax` portion!

Comment: I think your json file is getting cached!!

Comment: Please don't post code in comments ... update the question where it can be properly formatted and easy to read as part of the question

Comment: Set proper cahce headers on the server or add a chache breaking querystring. GET requests cache! If they did not, the net would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('../file/data.json',function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
</script>
```